# API integration using RxJava and Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

Hi  i am new to RxJava and Retrofit, and i am having API's like generate OTP and Check OTP , how to call these API's in android project for OTP generation and validation. I have to give mobile number, generated OTP has to received to mobile after this OTP validation also have to takes place.

Answer (score 0):

API's like generate OTP and Check OTP are also very much similar to other APIs,

In retrofit, you call generate OTP service call with call back once response success, you alert user to enter OTP and then verify with the OTP by calling Check OTP API inside the success block (once after user submits the OTP).

Comment: I am trying, thanks. if you have any example code please update here.